# What is the correct syntax for a multi-network multi-host Vagrantfile?

Tags: networking, ansible, vagrant

I'm trying to create several hosts that have multiple networks along with the term define.  I do not know Ruby and I'm not sure what is wrong with this syntax.

Can someone please offer some advice about the error?
As an aside, is there a best practice for the use of define syntax in Ruby?

NOTE: public_network below is the local LAN network (assigning static IPs).

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
# Ansible controller
config.vm.define "cent7ansiblecontroller" do |cent7ansiblecontroller|
  cent7ansiblecontroller.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
  # https://app.vagrantup.com/geerlingguy/boxes/centos7
  cent7ansiblecontroller.vm.hostname = "cent7ansiblecontroller"
  cent7ansiblecontroller.vm.network "hostonly", ip: "172.28.128.170"
  cent7ansiblecontroller.vm.network "public_network", ip: "10.10.10.170"
  end
end
```

Thank you!

Update:
Switching from hostonly to private_network seems to validate in Vagrant and allow for the machines to come up.

Not sure if hostonly is a valid option.

Found this: 
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/networking.html
"By default, private networks are host-only networks, ..."
And
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal

Answer (score 1):

#### Network

`hostonly` is not valid Vagrant. You just need to be clear on how far your connections should reach and how it relates to Vagrant's (and VirtualBox's) settings

- If you want the guests to communicate to the outside world, use Vagrant's directive `public_network`

  `<Object>.vm.network "public_network", ip: "<IP>"`
- If you want the guests to communicate to each other plus the host, you want VirtualBox's 'host-only network', which you get with Vagrant's `private_network`

  `<Object>.vm.network "private_network", ip: "<IP>"`
- If you want the guests to communicate only to each other, you want VirtualBox's 'internal network', which you get with Vagrant's `private_network` directive with `virtualbox__intnet: true` attribute

  `<Object>.vm.network "private_network", ip: "<IP>", virtualbox__intnet: true`

> This takes into account that you want fixed IPs. If you use DHCP or so, it changes. Go to [official docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/) for details.

#### Best practices

Your syntax is fine - the `do..end` works just like that. There's only a style problem: you have an inner block which is not indented.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
# Ansible controller
config.vm.define    # This should be indented
```

Instead, do:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "<Machine name>" do |<Object>|
    <Object>.vm.box ...
    ...
  end
end
```